# Availability of OpenGL extensions

Tags: opengl, driver, video-card

Is there a website/source that can tell you if graphics card X with driver version Y supports OpenGL extension Z? I've looked through Google and the release notes of some driver versions and I couldn't find anything like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here:
[**OpenGL status published on G-Truc Creation**](http://www.g-truc.net/project-0033.html#menu)

Comment: do not thank me, but G-Truc :)

Comment: I always die a little inside when I look at that matrix and see adoption of [`GL_EXT_direct_state_access`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/direct_state_access.txt) languishing on Intel, Mesa and OS X. It is basically what is left of the original Long's Peak fiasco, the extension is a mess but there is no excuse for only NV and AMD implementing it after _5_ years now.

Answer (score 1):

Also take a look at the [**OpenGL Extensions Viewer**](http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/). It allows you to see the extensions supported on your computer, and also includes a database showing which extensions are supported by a selection of over 700 other graphics cards.